# What is the word for the space between the hours marker in a clock face

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, there is a space between the number 4 and the number 5 in a clock. What is the name for this other than "space"

Comment: Why do you imagine there exists some special word for this?

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. A good question is going to demonstrate effort and research on the part of the poster. You would do well toedit this question to show what you have done to find an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @J.Taylor I eventually went through a list of words that clock makers use. I'll show work next time.

Comment: @tchrist I just assumed there was a word that clock makers would use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not specific for clocks, you can call it an **"interspace"** or **"interval"**.

> [**interspace**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/interspace) (noun) - A space between two things; an interval.

Answer (score 2):

Any such space (not necessarily on a clock-face) can be termed an ***interstice***.

M-W:

> **[interstice](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/interstice)**
>   *noun*
>
> **1 a**: a space that intervenes between things; especially :one between closely spaced things
>
> pesky weeds growing in the interstices between the flagstones